# Quickly uploading images to an imagehosting site and getting the URL

Tags: windows-xp, python, perl

A Perl or Python script would be perfect, only I've yet to find one. I saw some but they're all work in progress.

In short, I need a *[thing]* for quickly uploading an image to an imagehosting site (pick your favourite, I'm not choosy ...) and getting the URL. Flickr, imageshack, tinypic, ... doesn't matter, I just want to avoid the manual process of doing that.

Anyone ... open to all ideas which could kill time off this process.

Answer (score 2):

[image: enter link description here]

If you use Greenshot to generate a screenshot, you can instantly upload.

Comment: So far I'm using SnagIt (because it has excellent things for annotation and quickly displaying where the problem lies) but I'll check Greenshot out.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I connect my camera, DropBox automatically uploads my photos.  I can make the directory public to anyone or everyone.  If you're really not picky, it works great.  Plus I maintain the rights to all my pictures.

Comment: This is more of a case of uploading snapshots of troubleshooting some CAD issues and forgetting about them in two days. I have no wish to save them for a time longer then the discussion in progress where I illustrate the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Use the imageshack desktop uploader...  You may be able to do it without an account (which means images are deleted after 30 days) or just go clean out your account once in awhile.  The desktop uploader is nice because you can upload batches of images.

Just drop in the pictures you want to upload, they upload and it gives you the links.

http://toolbar.imageshack.us/windows-uploader/ImageShackUploader-2.2.0.msi  should be the installer for the desktop program